# Approximating an infinite Sum

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, analytic-number-theory, approximation-theory

I am interested in finding the approximate answer to the following infinite sum

\begin{equation}
\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}( l+a) \exp^{b{(l+c)}^2}
\end{equation}
in the case where $a>0 , b<0 , c>0$ and $a$ and $c$ are both large. Does any one know how to approach this problem and where to look for methods if I need to find the asymptotic answer to infinite sums?

Comment: Looks like a derivative of a theta function.

Comment: Could you explain why you said that

Comment: wouldn't that require a and c to be the same?

Comment: Subracting the same sum with $a$ replaced by $c$ gives a constant multiple of a value of theta function.

Comment: Could you please show how or tell where to look?

Comment: I mean where can I find that formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Approximating the sum by an integral, gives
$$F(a,b,c)=
\int_0^\infty( l+a) \exp\left[b{(l+c)}^2\right]\,dl=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } (a-c) \text{Erfc}\left(c\sqrt{-b} \right)}{2\sqrt{-b}}-\frac{e^{b c^2}}{2b}.$$
This should be accurate for large $c$. Here is a comparison for $b=-1$, $c=2a$ of the sum (blue) and the integral approximation (gold) as a function of $a$.

[image]

Comment: I badly need something very similar. Would it be possible to estimate the error term?

Comment: I am not sure how one would do that. I am looking for the formula with the theta function. Let me know if you have any idea about that one.